# Batman Arkham Knight 2015 Question about the controller

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I am curious as to what controller works with Arkham Knight PC, I have no issue using other games using x360ce. This is a screenshot that shows the controller map but what controller is it. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=687551726
Like it seems to be showing an LCD screen on the controller for Waynetech.
If anyone can help me figure this out it would be great I use a ps2 type gamepad and I use x360ce program for use with games that require the Xbox controller but i have no idea what kind of controller it's showing me nor have any idea what controller I should be trying to get or what software I could use.

Comment: That's a PS4 controller.  The screen is actually just a trackpad/button

Answer (score 4):

The controller in your screenshot is easy to identify, for many reasons.  One is that it says "DUALSHOCK 4 Wireless Controller" at the top.  It's a PlayStation 4 controller, which has a trackpad.  It seems like touching the trackpad brings up WayneTech.

I played Arkham Knight on PC with an Xbox 360 controller and an Xbox One controller.  It seems like anything that can emulate an Xbox 360 controller (like your x360ce software ought to) would work.

Comment: I have never seen a controller like this before DualShock controllers are common being a 4 said nothing to me about what console it came from.I have never used consoles, in any case, thanks for identifying it for me, the odd thing is I can't get a controller to work for this game. Perhaps I'll try buying the actual 360 and Xbox 1 controllers to try and get it working.I have never used a controller before but had bought one for GTA V it was advertised as something like DualShock 2 or 3 USB gamepad.